# How to keep watching mouse move outside iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page that has a draggable element implemented using JavaScript mouse events. If I open the page directly (not in an iframe), the element keeps moving when the cursor goes outside the browser window. But if I put the page in an iframe, JS doesn't emit `mousemove` events (the element stops) when the cursor goes outside the iframe in Chrome and Safari (works fine in Firefox).

You can try it with this demo by grabbing the element and moving it left and right above the demo:

```js
function handleMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
}

function handleMouseMove(event) {
  handle.style.transform = `translateX(${event.clientX - 50}px)`;
}

function handleMouseUp() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
}

const handle = document.querySelector('#handle')
handle.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
```

```css
#handle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="handle">Drag me</div>
```

How to make browser keep emitting `mousemove` events when the cursor moves outside the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `event.preventDefault()` from `handleMouseDown`. The element will move not only when the cursor is outside the iframe but even when it's outside the browser window. If you want to prevent text selection, you can use `user-select: none`:

```js
function handleMouseDown(event) {
  // Delete: event.preventDefault();
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
}

function handleMouseMove(event) {
  handle.style.transform = `translateX(${event.clientX - 50}px)`;
}

function handleMouseUp() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
}

const handle = document.querySelector('#handle')
handle.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
```

```css
#handle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  /* Add */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="handle">Drag me</div>
```

Also, if you cancel `mousedown` event, [pointermove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/pointermove_event) event won't fire outside the iframe too.